# Self-maps (dynamical systems) in several variables induced by functions $X^{n+1}\to X$

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

Self-maps $F:X\to X$ can be viewed as dynamic systems.

A function $f:X^{n+1}\to X$ induces a self-map $F:X^{n+1}\to X^{n+1}$,

$$ F(x_0\dots x_n):=
    (x_1, \ldots, x_n, f(x)) $$
for every $x:=(x_0, \ldots, x_n)\in X^{n+1}$.

**Question** What is known about such dynamic systems?

In particular, about the set of values obtained by iterating $F$ generated by an initial set or just one $(x_0, \ldots\ x_n)$?

Comment: Henon automorphisms $(x,y)\mapsto (y,P(y)-\lambda x)$ already have a quite rich dynamics (originally $(x,y)\mapsto (y,x+1-ay^2)$).